# Why not use free() in this instance

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, free, realloc

so I have another newbie question for you. This function is meant to read all the bytes from a passed in file, store them in the heap and then store the address to those bytes in the passed in 'content' parameter and the length in the passed in 'length' parameter.

```
bool load(FILE* file, BYTE** content, size_t* length)
{
if (file == NULL)
{
    return false;
}

//array to hold the bytes??
BYTE* buffer = malloc(sizeof(BYTE));

//To hold the number of bytes currently loaded
size_t size = 0;


//Pointer to keep track of where I am adding the data to in buffer

//get all the bytes from the file and put them in the buffer
for(int i = fgetc(file); i != EOF; i = fgetc(file))
{
    buffer[size] = (char) i; 
    size++;
    buffer = realloc(buffer, size + 1);
}

//dereference length
*length = size;

//derefernce content
*content = buffer;

//free(buffer);
return true;
}
```

So previously the larger program that this function was a part of did not work, yet when I commented out the

```
free(buffer);
```

call at the bottom my program started to work perfectly. I was motivated to comment this out when I came across a double free error. So my question is: why does calling free in this instance cause an error?

My intuition tells me that it is because the data that

```
*content
```

points to is now "deleted" and so my program wasn't working. Furthermore somewhere later on in the code I free content* as well, which is where the double free error comes from. However for some reason I am inclined to believe that the data is not actually "deleted".

Sorry if this is a lot, I have been confused by memory allocation, free, and pointers for a while and am trying to gain a deeper understanding.

Comment: Just a note. Your allocation by repeatedly calling `realloc` for every character read from the file is about the most inefficient use of `realloc` you can dream up. Instead, allocate some reasonable number of bytes (e.g. `1024`, `4096`, or more) and then keep an index and read characters from the file until the index (`+1`) reaches your original limit, then call `realloc` and allocate another `4096`, etc. and repeat. How many calls to `realloc` will you make on a 1-Megabyte file?

Comment: What David said, … Or double the amount of space allocated each time you call `realloc()` — optionally doing a final shrinking `realloc()` if there is too much extra space to spare (e.g. if there's more than 1 KiB of unused space).

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin the inner working of the `realloc` function will just be to do that same check and then invoke some other function if the current capacity is exceeded, so I would argue that it unnecessarily complicates OP's code to hoist those checks up. Probably the OS supplies blocks of several kilobytes at least.

Comment: "for some reason I am inclined to believe that the data is not actually "deleted" - this isn't very logical

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When allocating memory (or resources in general), you must make sure that you have clear ownership semantics.  Who owns the allocated resource and is responsible for freeing it?

For a function that allocate resources, sane semantics are that the function returns the allocated resource if successful, and unless otherwise specified, the caller owns that resource.  If the function fails, the caller should not have to perform any cleanup.

Your `load()` function allocates a buffer.  Throughout most of its function body, `load()` owns that buffer.  Just before it returns success, it effectively *transfers* ownership of that buffer to the caller (via the `content` output argument).  If `load()` had a failure point after allocating the buffer, then it should call `free(buffer)` along that failure path.

---

I also feel compelled to point out a few issues with your code:

```
BYTE* buffer = malloc(sizeof(BYTE));
```

You should test if `malloc` fails.  Additionally, `sizeof (BYTE)` is not useful since it is, by definition, 1.

```
buffer = realloc(buffer, size + 1);
```

This is poor practice.  If `realloc` fails, you will lose the old value of `buffer` and will leak memory.  It's better to do:

```
BYTE* tmp = realloc(buffer, size + 1);
if (tmp == NULL)
{
    free(buffer);
    return false;
}
buffer = tmp;
```

Finally, growing your buffer by 1 byte every time is very inefficient.  More typical practices would be to double the buffer size or to grow it by a larger amounts.